# ExtJs TabPanel Scrollbar behaviour if Tab items bigger than tab size

Tags: extjs, scrollbar, behavior, tabpanel

i need to make works this simple example to understand the behaviour of TabPanel.
I have read a lot of thread about it and the answer is often
-make the item (grid in this example) directly child of tabpanel
or
-set grid size fixed to fill the entire space of tab

BUT
my target is to obtain an item of the tab with size greater than the tab size so the tab must have scrollbar
I can't set the item(grid) directly child of tabpanel because the tabpanel layout fix the size of the tab so you can't have scrollbars

This code build the tabpanel:

```
var vp = new Ext.Viewport({

    layout: 'border',
    id: 'view1',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'north',
        title: 'north'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'east',
        title: 'east'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'center',
        title: 'center',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            title: 'Tabpanel',
            id: 'tabpanel',
            activeTab: 'tab',
            autoWidth: false,
            autoHeight: false,
            defaults: {
                autoScroll: true
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'grid',
                id: 'tab',
                autoWidth: false,
                autoHeight: false,
                defaults: {
                    autoScroll: true
                },

                items: grid
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'west',
        title: 'west'
    }

    ]
});
vp.show();

alert("tabpanel: " + Ext.getCmp('tabpanel').getWidth() + "\ngrid: " +  Ext.getCmp('grid').getWidth());
```

And this code build the grid (taken from ext example)

```
   var myData = [
    ['3m Co',                               71.72, 0.02,  0.03,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Alcoa Inc',                           29.01, 0.42,  1.47,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Altria Group Inc',                    83.81, 0.28,  0.34,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['American Express Company',            52.55, 0.01,  0.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['American International Group, Inc.',  64.13, 0.31,  0.49,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['AT&T Inc.',                           31.61, -0.48, -1.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Boeing Co.',                          75.43, 0.53,  0.71,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Caterpillar Inc.',                    67.27, 0.92,  1.39,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Citigroup, Inc.',                     49.37, 0.02,  0.04,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company', 40.48, 0.51,  1.28,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Exxon Mobil Corp',                    68.1,  -0.43, -0.64, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['General Electric Company',            34.14, -0.08, -0.23, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['General Motors Corporation',          30.27, 1.09,  3.74,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Hewlett-Packard Co.',                 36.53, -0.03, -0.08, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Honeywell Intl Inc',                  38.77, 0.05,  0.13,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Intel Corporation',                   19.88, 0.31,  1.58,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['International Business Machines',     81.41, 0.44,  0.54,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Johnson & Johnson',                   64.72, 0.06,  0.09,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['JP Morgan & Chase & Co',              45.73, 0.07,  0.15,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['McDonald\'s Corporation',             36.76, 0.86,  2.40,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Merck & Co., Inc.',                   40.96, 0.41,  1.01,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Microsoft Corporation',               25.84, 0.14,  0.54,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Pfizer Inc',                          27.96, 0.4,   1.45,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['The Coca-Cola Company',               45.07, 0.26,  0.58,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['The Home Depot, Inc.',                34.64, 0.35,  1.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['The Procter & Gamble Company',        61.91, 0.01,  0.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['United Technologies Corporation',     63.26, 0.55,  0.88,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Verizon Communications',              35.57, 0.39,  1.11,  '9/1 12:00am'],            
    ['Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.',               45.45, 0.73,  1.63,  '9/1 12:00am']
];
    function change(val) {
    if (val > 0) {
        return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '</span>';
    } else if (val < 0) {
        return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
    }
    return val;
}

function pctChange(val) {
    if (val > 0) {
        return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '%</span>';
    } else if (val < 0) {
        return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '%</span>';
    }
    return val;
}
var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: [
       {name: 'company'},
       {name: 'price',      type: 'float'},
       {name: 'change',     type: 'float'},
       {name: 'pctChange',  type: 'float'},
       {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'}
    ]
});

store.loadData(myData);

// create the Grid
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {
            id       :'company',
            header   : 'Company', 
            width    : 500, 
            sortable : true, 
            dataIndex: 'company'
        },
        {
            header   : 'Price', 
            width    : 75, 
            sortable : true, 
            renderer : 'usMoney', 
            dataIndex: 'price'
        },
        {
            header   : 'Change', 
            width    : 75, 
            sortable : true, 
            dataIndex: 'change'
        },
        {
            header   : '% Change', 
            width    : 75, 
            sortable : true, 
            dataIndex: 'pctChange'
        },
        {
            header   : 'Last Updated', 
            width    : 300, 
            sortable : true, 
            dataIndex: 'lastChange'
        },

    ],
    stripeRows: true,
    autoExpandColumn: 'company',
    height: 1000,
    width: 2000,
    title: 'Array Grid',
    id:'grid',
    // config options for stateful behavior
    stateful: true,
    autoscroll:true,
    stateId: 'grid'
});
```

The alert result is

```
tabpanel: 1297
grid: 2000
```

but no scrollbar appears

Answer (score 0):

The TabPanel is not receiving a height from its surrounding layout due to how it is being placed.

One option is to set the center region panel to a fit layout:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel', 
    region: 'east', 
    title: 'east'   
},
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    region: 'center',
    title: 'center',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        title: 'Tabpanel'
        // ...
    }
},   
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    region: 'west',
    title: 'west'
}
```

However, unless you plan to do something more than just host a TabPanel in the center region you are better off just making the TabPanel the center region:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',  
    region: 'east',  
    title: 'east'    
},
{
     xtype: 'tabpanel',
     region: 'center',
     title: 'Tabpanel'
     // ...
},   
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    region: 'west',
    title: 'west'
}
```

Also, you do not need to set the autoScroll property on the GridPanel or on the TabPanel's defaults, and you may in fact be causing some undesirable rendering by doing so.

Comment: Immediate and clear, thank you!!!On ext documentation I've read that the center region force the single specified item to fill the entire region (if you don't specify the size) but it isn't enough as I can see. Thank you

Comment: The panel you place in the center region does indeed fill the available space. The problem was you were placing yet another panel inside the center region's panel without the layout necessary to give it similar treatment.